# Error in 'make && make install': makefile:37: ***missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, cmake

I tried to follow the installation steps of 'SelfTarget' from GitHub steps here:
https://github.com/felicityallen/SelfTarget

Typing 
`make && make install`
I get the error message

`makefile:37: ***missing separator. Stop.`

The Makefile code is

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "NMake Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 3.13

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all

.PHONY : default_target

# Allow only one "make -f Makefile2" at a time, but pass parallelism.
.NOTPARALLEL:


#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canonical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:


.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list


# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:


# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:

.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

!IF "$(OS)" == "Windows_NT"
NULL=
!ELSE
NULL=nul
!ENDIF
SHELL = cmd.exe

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = C:\...\cmake.exe

[…]
```

I.e., line 37 is

```
!ELSE
```

Do you have ideas what's wrong and how to solve this problem? 
I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: I tried ```nmake``` and got the error message ```the command "nmake" is either misspelled or could not be found.```

Answer (score 2):

You've used `NMake Makefiles` generator, so you need to call `nmake` instead of `make`. If you are or Unix-like OS, use `Unix Makefiles`.